# Nested react & redux apps - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an existing standalone auth app written in Angular, which was easily passed around within an Angular ecosystem when needed, or worked fine by itself. In a hacky way I was able to use it in a view in a react app, but there was a requirement to update it, so I've rewritten it in react and redux.

Problem is, I'm having a much more difficult time integrating it into the aforementioned react app. Has anyone done anything like this before, or am I going to have to require all the different pieces separately and 'reassemble' it if I need to use it in other react/redux applications?

Comment: how are your projects being 'built' are you using a tool like browersify or webpack? if yes: then you can export your app as a component and use it anywhere in you existing app. If you are doing something more 'traditional' then you could have two separate divs -- one for each app to render into. Your question has many different answers so I would suggest you give as much detail as humanly possible in order to get an answer that suits your specific situation.

Comment: Having played around with it for a while, I think it's actually an issue with react and redux being included twice, moving them to peerDependencies got me a lot closer. Will get it to work somehow, I just haven't been able to find anything online of anyone doing something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I got this working. The issue was that react, redux, immutable.js etc were all being bundled twice. I just had to move them in to devDependencies instead of dependencies in my 'inner' app, and then everything worked as expected.

I had a separate issue in that my 'outer' app was using webpack and the 'inner' browserify, so I swapped out webpack.

The error I was getting was an invariant error, which wasn't particularly helpful but there you go. Hopefully this is useful for others in a similar situation.